# Change column names according to a parameter file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file(parameter_column.xlsx) that I use for renaming the columns of another file (filenow)

parameter_column gives me a dataframe like this for example:

```
      col1     col2    
1     colA     A      
2     colB     B
```

and filenow gives me a dataframe like this:

```
     colA     colB      colC          
1     1         3        5      
2     2         4        6
```

and what i'm trying to do is rename the columns of filenow according to the data in parameter_columns like so:

```
     A     B      colC          
1    1     3        5      
2    2     4        6
```

I've been tryning by using loops or dict but I  can't seem to figure out how to do so.

I'll appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`df.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) on `axis=1` /`(columns=)`

```
filenow.rename(columns=dict(parameter[['col1','col2']].to_numpy()))
```

---

```
   A  B  colC
1  1  3     5
2  2  4     6
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but sadly it does not respond to my problem. I have to go through the file "parameter_colmun" and match the column name in "filenow" with the one in "parameter_column". they are files that are constantly updated,

Comment: What I need is a loop that goes through both dataframes and match every column with the other, but I can't find a way to do it